# Query on backslash character

Tags: java, escaping

Below is the line that builds the path of a directory in java.

Here, `File.separator` is "\" on windows and "/" on Unix.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "workspace" + 
                                              File.separator + "JavaCode";
```

If i hardcode the path, it should look as shown below:

```
File path = new File("C:\\users\\david\\workspace\\JavaCode");
```

My question:

Why do we mention `\\` in second case?

Comment: Because that's how you write a single backslash in a _string literal_

Comment: That hardcoded example will not compile: you assign a `File` to the variable `path` of type `String`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 it was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, with a string, `\` is an *escape* character: it says to interpret the following character in a special way (which is why `\n` isn't an `n`).  In your case, you want `\` itself to be interpretted specailly by *not* treating it special, so you need 2 of them: the first says "treat the next character special", the next gets treated specially *for a `\`*.

Comment: But why did i not require two backslash while using `File.separator`?

Comment: How do you know that isn't what is *in* File.separator?

Comment: you mean `S.O.P(File.separator);` actually has "\\" and displays "\" on console? for forward slash `/` this should not be the case right?

Comment: The value of File.separator is whatever is appropriate for that environment; / doesn't need to be escaped (if that is what you are asking).

Answer (score 2):

This is because of how string literals are defined in Java. A backslash is used for some escape sequences (such as `"\n"`, `"\r"` and others), therefore a literal backslash is also an escape sequence (`"\\"`).

Back to your code however, don't bother, use [java.nio.file](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API) instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "workspace",
    "JavaCode");
```

Works for every OS the JVM (7+) runs on.

It will correctly return a `Path` for `"C:\\users\\david\\workspace\\JavaCode"` on your machine the same way it returns one for `"/home/fge/workspace/JavaCode"` on mine.